# Mongodb : cannot pass logical session id unless fully upgraded to featureCompatibilityVersion 3.6

Tags: mongodb

I am facing this problem

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.21                                                                                       
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb                                                       
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("cfd05935-a93e-469e-8c5c-d3b526905f57") }                                         
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3                                                                                             
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: cannot pass logical session id unless fully 
upgraded to featureCompatibilityVersion 3.6. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-feature-compatibility .
```

while upgrading my MongoDB to version 3.6.

I tried all possible solutions such as

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

I also tried what is suggested in error message.
The URL http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-feature-compatibility doesn't give much help.

Can someone please give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )

This command will throw same error if a database is preselected:

[image: robo db error]

You should issue this command without selecting any database, preferably from terminal:

[image: terminal]